# Data Dependencies: MIPS

Tags: dependencies, mips

I'm having some trouble understanding what data dependencies exist in the following code:

```
SW R16, -100(R6)
LW R4, 8(R16)
ADD R5, R4, R4
```

Here's where I think the dependencies are:

```
SW R16, -100(R6)  // RAR on R16 from SW to LW
LW R4, 8(R16)     // RAW on R4 from LW to ADD
ADD R5, R4, R4
```

Are there any dependencies I'm missing?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the RAR you flagged on the first instruction. Is there another `sw` instruction that precedes that one?

Comment: There isn't.  I'm just wondering if the only dependency is on R4.  I'm just not sure whether there is more than one dependency in this code due to SW and LW sharing R16.

Comment: O, sorry I get it now. Everything looks good.